# How to allow ws:// instead of localhost:// for tornado

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

I have the following basic tornado app:

```
import tornado.web

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """Regular HTTP handler to serve the ping page"""
    def get(self):
        self.write("OK")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", IndexHandler), 
    ])
    app.listen(8000)
    print 'Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000'
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This will run on `"http://localhost:8000"`. How would I get this to run and accept connections at `ws://localhost:8000`?

Comment: You are going to need a websocket server and it is going to have a different endpoint then for normal HTTP.

Comment: @KlausD. -- you mean which cannot be done in Tornado? What would be an example application in python where that could be done?

Comment: It can be done in Tornado. At least take a look at official doc: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tornado.web.RequestHandler` is used for accepting HTTP requests. For websockets, you need to use [`tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler).

---

Another thing to note is that you can't visit a websocket url directly from the browser. That is, you can't type `ws://localhost:8000` in the address bar and expect to connect to the websocket. That is not how websockets work.

A websocket connection is an upgrage connection. Which means, you first have to visit a url via HTTP and then use Javascript to upgrade to websocket.

See an example about how to connect to websocket using Javascript at [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Example).